# The reference 'Microsoft.Activities' could not be added to the project while adding workflow to SharePoint app

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to create a Workflow in a Sharepoint 2013 app, but whenever I try to "add" - "new item" - "workflow" I get the following error:

> *The reference 'Microsoft.Activities' could not be added to the project. This wizard will continue to run, but the resulting project
>   may not build properly.*

Workflow designer opens, but when  I try to add something to it, for example a SingleTask I get an error:

> *Cannot create an instance of "SingleTaskFactory". "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Activities,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified."*

My dev system: Windows 7, Visual Studio 2013 Pro (Update 3), Office developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013 ENU (12.0.30626).

Server is a SharePoint 2013 Standard.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this Assembly is sometime missing after installation of Visual Studio 2013 or Workflow Manager. Just copy it from a working System. It should be in the GAC (C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Activities) Of xourse you must already have Workflowmanager and Client installed on System e.g. via Web Plattform Installer. I suggest verify via SharePoint Designer that you can create SharePoint 2013 Workflows.

Comment: Found the dll on a system with SharePoint installed, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.